# sort and pattern match an json

Tags: javascript, regex, json, search

Am having a json like below,

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Tiruchengode",
        "label": "Tiruchengode"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Coimbatore",
        "label": "Coimbatore"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Erode",
        "label": "Erode"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Madurai",
        "label": "Madurai"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Salem",
        "label": "Salem"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Tiruchirappalli",
        "label": "Tiruchirappalli"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "freq": "1",
        "value": "Tirunelveli",
        "label": "Tirunelveli"
    }
]
```

I need to pattern match it with label item in this json (ie), If I type **tiru**, then it has to result label items having **tiru** substrings in it.If its a single item array I know how to pattern match and sort it. Here am completely unaware that, how to pattern match using label item in the array. Is it possible to?. I need to do with Pure javascript, any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse() will help convert the jsonString to JsonObject then just iterate the object use indexOf for pattern matching.

```
var jsonString = '[{"id": "1","freq": "1","value": "Tiruchengode","label": "Tiruchengode"},{"id": "2","freq": "1","value": "Coimbatore","label": "Coimbatore"},{"id": "3","freq": "1","value": "Erode","label": "Erode"},{"id": "4","freq": "1","value": "Madurai","label": "Madurai"},{"id": "5","freq": "1","value": "Salem","label": "Salem"},{"id": "6","freq": "1","value": "Tiruchirappalli","label": "Tiruchirappalli"},{"id": "7","freq": "1","value": "Tirunelveli","label": "Tirunelveli"}]';

    var jsonObjects = JSON.parse(jsonString);       
    var pattern = "tiru";

    for(var key in jsonObjects){
        var label = jsonObjects[key].label.toUpperCase();       
        if(label.indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase()) != -1){
            document.write(label+"<br/>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functional array methods introduced in JavaScript 1.6, specifically `filter`:

```
var search = 'tiru';
var results = obj.filter(function(item) {
    var a = item.label.toUpperCase();
    var b = search.toUpperCase();
    return a.indexOf(b) >= 0;
});
```

If you wanted labels only, you can then use `map` to return only that property alone:

```
var labels = obj.filter(function(item) {
    var a = item.label.toUpperCase();
    var b = search.toUpperCase();
    return a.indexOf(b) >= 0;
}).map(function(item) {
    return item.label;
});
```

Essentially, `filter` is a method available to any `Array` which returns a new `Array` containing only those members for which the supplied function return true.

Comment: indexOf doesn't ignores case, convert both the label and pattern to uppercase while checking >=0.